# How to combine two MySQL columns to one column?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I want to convert this MySQL table:

```
title1 | title2 |type  
-------+--------+----
qwe1   | qwe2   | 3  
asd1   | asd2   | 7
```

to this table in PHP

```
title | type  
------+-----
asd1  | 7  
asd2  | 7  
qwe1  | 3  
qwe1  | 3
```

But I don't know how to order the PHP table by the first column correctly.

(This is the code I am currently using)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY title1, title2";   
$pager = new PS_Pagination( $dbh, $sql, 3, 4, null );//pagination class
$rs = $pager->paginate(); 

while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['title1']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['type']}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['title2']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['type']}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}       

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I am curious why do you need that? Are yu sure your table design is all right?

Answer (score 9):

In SQL itself you can do it using `UNION`. And use `ORDER BY` for the whole query!

```
SELECT `title1` AS `title`, `type`
FROM `table`
UNION
SELECT `title2` AS `title`, `type`
FROM `table`
ORDER BY `title` ASC
```

#### Output

```
+-------+------+
| TITLE | TYPE |
+-------+------+
|  asd1 |    7 |
|  asd2 |    7 |
|  qwe1 |    3 |
|  qwe2 |    3 |
+-------+------+
```

#### Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff9cf/1

Comment: Note that `AS` is not required in second query.

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
SELECT 'title1' AS 'title', 'type' from 'table'
UNION
SELECT 'title2' AS 'title', 'type' from 'table'
ORDER BY 'title'
```

Hopefully I got the syntax right.

Essentially you want to do two queries and merge the result, which is what UNION does.

EDIT (see other answer for difference between UNION and UNION ALL).

Answer (score 4):

Use As to rename columns to gt the same structure before using [**Union**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

```
SELECT title1 as title, type
FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT title2 as title, type
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use UNION:

```
SELECT title1, type
FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT title2, type
FROM YourTable
```

If you don't want to have duplicates, you can remove use UNION instead of UNION ALL.

--EDIT

As has been suggested, if your intentions were to ORDER these results as well, just add an ORDER BY clause and alias your column:

```
SELECT title1 title, type
FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT title2 title, type
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY title
```

Good luck.

Comment: I think the main issue here is the sorting. So you should probably add `ORDER BY type, title` to your query with the alias added to the single SELECT statements.

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig -- I didn't think the OP was asking how to ORDER, but rather how to get the UNION -- they were attempting to get the UNION with an ORDER.  Easy enough to add the ORDER BY clause though...

Answer (score 2):

You need [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

i.e.

```
select * from (select title1 as title, type
from table
union
select title2 as title, type
from table) order by title
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question you want to concantinate title1+title2 and then order.

I dont get it why everyone is using unions

```
Select concat(title1,title2) title, type
from yourTable
order by title asc
```

Would do the job

edit: cant write code formatted text from an iphone. Thanks fthiella